# Why this code throws an NullPointerException?

Tags: java

im new to Java. I found this example in a book. I expected it to print "ab" or "abc", but it throws exception instead. Can somebody explain why it happens? Thanks in advance.

```
public class Test { 
    class A { 
        String str = "ab"; 

        A() { 
            printLength(); 
        } 

        void printLength() { 
            System.out.println(str.length()); 
        } 
    } 

    class B extends A { 
        String str = "abc"; 

        void printLength() { 
            System.out.println(str.length()); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new Test().new B(); 
    } 
}
```

Here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at c.Test$B.printLength(Test.java:25)
    at c.Test$A.<init>(Test.java:13)
    at c.Test$B.<init>(Test.java:21)
    at c.Test.main(Test.java:30)
```

Comment: Every exception should have stacktrace. Please post it.

Comment: new Test().new B();  is it correct.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` is constructed before `B`. In `A` constructor you call `printLength` which is overridden in class `B`. But `str` in class `B` is not instantiated yet, and will be `null`.

Therefore you get a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Just curious, isn't A also having `str` ? Then why the NPE?

Comment: Because the overridden method is called preferentially.(Note that in C++ the behaviour is undefined.)

Comment: can I change the code so it use field str from A class?

Comment: Sorry, still didn't understand - `Because the overridden method is called preferentially`  what do you mean by preferentially?

Comment: It means that the overridden method will be called unless you specifically state otherwise.

Comment: Because you're inside a method in class `B`, and class `B` has a field `str` which shadows the one with the same name in class `A`.

Comment: Ok, also, I did this testing - https://ideone.com/JQ3IQS - According to the prints the B's str is getting initialized (`Blah3` is the first print) - then why is it null in the `printLength()` function?

Answer (score 0):

See error is in

```
  A() { 
       printLength();           
    }
```

As when you do new B() then as B is sub class of A so the A() will be called as first statement of B() which is default in your case
In A() you are trying to access str of class B but the initialization phase still not completed as the constructor of B() yet executed.
So error occurs.

Hope I am able to help.
Don't try to start execution from constructor as it is meant to initialize your attributes.

Thanks.